# Using a .PEM key without a password on OSX, but asking for password

Tags: macos, mac, ssh

I have a PEM key named relatient2.pem that I was given by a client I'm working for. I've already put it in my ~/.ssh folder and have given it permissions of 600.

When running: ssh ec2-user@relatient.net, it's asking for a password but it shouldn't need one to access the server. Should only need the key. What can I do about making this work?

Answer (score -1):

I got this working by adding: `-i relatient2.pem` as a SSH option.

Comment: You could specify an `IdentityFile` file in your local configuration to use this automatically.  See man ssh_config.